# Vue :page don't display after add router-link

Tags: vue.js, router, routerlink

I have this template :

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div v-for="course in courses" :key="course.id">
            <router-link>{{course.body_ku}}</router-link>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import {myUrl} from '../components/Constants'
export default {
    data:function(){
        return{
            courses :[]
        }
    },
    created:function(){
        const url = myUrl + 'category_post/2'
        this.axios.get(url).then((response)=>{
            this.courses = response.data
        })
    }
}
</script>
```

it is not display anything ,but when I remove router-link it works correctly

Answer (score 0):

You need to load and register VueRouter to be able to use its components.

```
import VueRouter from "vue-router";
Vue.use(VueRouter)
```

Comment: I did ,and I used it anothe component and worked ,but not work on this

Comment: Doesn't `<router-link>` need a `:to` property? [https://router.vuejs.org/api/#router-link-props](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#router-link-props)

Answer (score 0):

This means your vue-router version is too high.

Just reinstall a lower version:

```
npm install vue-router@3.2.0
```

Then re-run:

```
npm run serve
```